# How to improve efficiency of this json search

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, search

I have some json data:

```
var data = {
  "version": "2.0",
  "result": {
      "0": [418789, 418790, 418791],
      "1": [431961, 431962, 431963], 
  }
};
```

And I have the value x I am looking for which in this case x = **431962**
So to do this I have written a search function provided below:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(data.result).length; i++) {
  for (var p = 0; p < Object.values(data.result)[i].length; p++) {
    if (Object.values(data.result)[i][p] == 418789) {
      console.log(Object.keys(data.result)[i])
    }
  }
}
```

However my issue is that this search function consists of 2 for loops which are nested so the speed is incredibly slow when searching through a large amount of JSON data, however I cannot seem to come up with a solution on how to improve efficiency and speed here.

This search is trying to find which key the value x exists in, where the key names in reality random names in no specific order, and the JSON data has a couple thousand keys with each array containing around 50 values from 1 to 1,000,000

Comment: It is hard to understand the logic of your search, can you explain what all of this for?

Comment: No you don't: what you're showing is a _normal javascript_ object with superfluous quotes around the keys, and a slightly silly way to represent the nested array `result`... JSON is just a string of meaningless-until-you-parse-it letters and numbers =). So you're trying check whether there is any combination of `i` and `j` for which `data.result[i][j]` includes your value, if I'm reading your post correctly?

Comment: yes that is correct @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i am looking to see if data.result[i][j] contains the value i am looking for which in this case is 418789, and then i print data.result[i]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One improvement you can make is to store references to the specific object/array you are working with so you don't have to return back to the Object.keys(...) again and again.

```js
let data = {
  "version": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "0": [418789, 418790, 418791],
    "1": [431961, 431962, 431963],
  }
};

function findWhichArrayContainsValue(val) {
  for (key in data.result) {
    const candidateArray = data.result[key];
    if (candidateArray.includes(val)) {
      return candidateArray;
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}

console.log(findWhichArrayContainsValue(418789));

console.log(findWhichArrayContainsValue(898989));
```